# PrimeNg Data list Not working in Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I have a data list using primeng but I'm getting this error when running the app:

> Can't bind to 'value' since it isn't a known property of 'p-dataList'

By html file is:

```
<p-dataList [value]="cars">
  <ng-template let-car pTemplate="item">
      Car content
  </ng-template>
</p-dataList>
```

My component file is:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
}

export class DataListDemo implements OnInit {

      cars: Car[];

      constructor(private carService: CarService) { }

      ngOnInit() {
          this.carService.getCarsLarge().then(cars => this.cars = cars);
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add the following to your app.module.ts and add it to the imports module list

```
import { DataTableModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
```